# How to create multiple columns per row in CSV with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-2.1

Ok, I have a hash which contains several properties. I wanted certain properties of this hash to be added to a CSV file.

Here's what I've written:

```
    require 'csv'
    require 'curb'
    require 'json'

    arr = []

    CSV.foreach('test.csv') do | row |
        details = []
        details << result['results'][0]['formatted_address']
        result['results'][0]['address_components'].each do | w |
            details << w['short_name']
        end
        arr << details
    end

    CSV.open('test_result.csv', 'w') do | csv |
        arr.each do | e |
            csv << [e]
        end
      end
    end
```

All works fine apart from the fact the I get each like so:

["something", "300", "something", "something", "something", "something", "something", "GB", "something"]

As an array, which I do not want. I want each element of the array in a new column. The problem is that I do not know how many items I'll have otherwise I could something like this:

```
CSV.open('test_result.csv', 'w') do | csv |
        arr.each do | e |
            csv << [e[0], e[1], ...]
        end
      end
    end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not do `csv << e` ?

Comment: It is indeed! Do you want to add as answer so I can mark it appropriately? Cheers

Comment: Yeah sure :3. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `csv << [e]` to `csv << e`.